# Can anyone please provide hive udf code for truncating particular column?

Tags: hive-udf

I have a column that contain double value 42.2223. I want to truncate the last four digits of this particular column.

Can any one please provide hive UDF for this particular scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to truncate the last four digits and get an integer, you can use the built-in functions `floor(double a)` or `ceiling(double a)`, depending on the the kind of rounding (upper or lower) that you want.

If you wanted your double to be truncated to `d` decimal places (and get a double, instead of an integer), you could use `round(double a, int d)`.

EDITED

In order to round without truncating, you can use this

`CAST((column * 100) AS int)/100`

Comment: But if i have a value of 35.35623 it will round off the value to 35.36. I dont want to round it off. I want it to be truncated(35.35)

Comment: @AkhilVishwa So in this case, you would want the result to be `35`?

Comment: No. I want the result as 35.35. I need first two numbers after decimal and it should not be rounded off rather it should be truncated.

Comment: @AkhilVishwa Try this `CAST((column * 100) AS int)/100`

Comment: @AkhilVishwa I'm glad it worked :-) I'll update the answer in case you wanted to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote an UDF for the above question where we can specify number of characters it can be truncated

```
package com.hive.udf.truncate;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
public class Trunc extends UDF {
    public double evaluate(double input,int numberOfDecimals){
       if ( input > 0) {
         return new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(input)).setScale(numberOfDecimals, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).doubleValue();
            } 
       else {
         return new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(input)).setScale(numberOfDecimals, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING).doubleValue();
        }
    }
}
```